# What's the opposite of jam?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if there's an antonym for jam as in "they jammed our radio signals". Is there? I looked up dictionaries and thesauruses and I haven't found a single antonym for the verb jam as in "jamming a radio signal". There are antonym related to different definitions of jam, but not the one I am looking for. What are the words that can qualify as an antonym?

I am thinking there are phrasal verbs or other verbs that are not quite the same as antonyms that could be provided as answers, but I am not sure if these words can technically be used as antonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intention matters here. Do you want a better signal because the one available is poor? Then *amplify* or *de-noise/denoise* work. However, if you want to remedy a jam on the signal, you would *unjam* it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "to boost".

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boost) :

: to raise the voltage of or across (an electric circuit)

Here's an example from [Reverso.context.net](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/boost+signals):

"So you broke into that satellite facility to boost your signal."